# Regular expression to find path from filename

Tags: regex

I need to replace the directory structure or the file-path from the file name with whitespace.

Input text :

```
D:\LIGHTNING_ProductSecurity\BACKEND\CORE\dal\src\main\java\com\adminserver\dal\AuthPlanDal.java
```

Output text :

```
D:\LIGHTNING_ProductSecurity\BACKEND\CORE\dal\src\main\java\com\adminserver\dal\
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Please provide a sample input/output. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*\\)
```

Will return only the patch preceding the file name.

Comment: No need to put a capture group around all your regex, but this is a fun use of greediness indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex for search, and replace with empty.

```
(?<=\\)[^\\]+$
```

This one is matching the last portion(i.e. `AuthPlanDal.java`) after the `\` from the file path.

Anyone can try this [at online](http://regex101.com/r/dE9hT5).

Comment: I need to get the part preceeding AuthPlanDal.java

Comment: If you want to get the path preceding then use only use regex: `(.*\\)`

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
string path = @"D:\LIGHTNING_ProductSecurity\BACKEND\CORE\dal\src\main\java\com\adminserver\dal\AuthPlanDal.java";
string fullPathWithoutFilename = Path.GetFullPath(path).Replace(Path.GetFileName(path), "");
```